# localStorage [' http://mail.example.com'] is accessible to localStorage ['mail.example.com:8080']?

Tags: local-storage

I was reading this but I want some clarification for an example that I have

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799(v=vs.85).aspx
>
> Each domain and subdomain has its own separate local storage area.
>   Domains can access the storage areas of subdomains, and subdomains can
>   access the storage areas of parent domains. For example,
>   localStorage['example.com'] is accessible to example.com and any of
>   its subdomains. The subdomain localStorage['www.example.com'] is
>   accessible to example.com, but not to other subdomains, such as
>   mail.example.com.

So the website example can be mail.example.com or go.example.com so on

1. localStorage [' mail.example.com'] saves data in a storage , can    [' mail.example.com']  access that data ?
2. localStorage [' mail.example.com'] is accessible to localStorage ['mail.example.com:8080'] ?
3. localStorage [' mail.example.com'] is accessible to localStorage ['mail.example.com:80'] ?
   4.localStorage [' http://mail.example.com'] is accessible to localStorage ['mail.example.com:22'] ?

Comment: so where is the question?

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson I am trying to understand  this 2 questions :       
           1.  localStorage [' mail.example.com'] saves data in a storage , can [' mail.example.com'] access that data ?                                           
             2. localStorage [' mail.example.com'] is accessible to localStorage ['mail.example.com:8080'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two addresses you show here have the same domain and subdomain.

```
protocol subdomain domain      port
http://  go.       example.com (defaults to 80)
http://  go.       example.com :8080
```

So this behaviour matches the documentation you have linked to.

Comment: thanks @Shadow for your  reply . So doesn't matter witch port is as long as is the same sub domain ?

Comment: That's what both your personal experience and the documentation says. If you need to test this, you could try connecting via the IP address though. Depends on your set up as to whether that is feasible though.

Comment: I understand , thanks for your advice . Testing is the best solution to see if is working or not .

Comment: I certainly agree. Please don't forget to upvote/accept this answer if it has helped you.

Comment: I can't not upvode because I am new here but I have accepted. thanks for tell me, is my first time that I have done the accept thing.It help me